# How to travel from Chicago International Airport to Bloomington, IN

Tags: usa, budget, indiana

A friend of mine is travelling to US for first time. She is planning to land at O'Hare Chicago Intl. airport and from there she will be travelling to Bloomington, IN.

Flight tickets from her source to Chicago is way cheaper than that to Indianapolis.

What are the best options she has for reaching Bloomington, IN. And if possible what are the respective approx. cost for those options. This is important to know because, if the cost for best/safe travel is more than the amount she is saving for taking flight to Chicago over Indianapolis, then she would better take Indianapolis.

PS: She will be with 2 humongous luggage

Thanks.

Comment: This is a bit broad with lots of options.  RideSharing to IU, Bus to Indianapolis and then to IU, etc, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: There are two international airports in Chicago: O'Hare and Midway. Probably your friend is going to arrive at O'Hare (which is the one with the most international routes), but it would be a good thing to write that explicitly in the question.

Comment: @HenningMakholm thanks for mentioning that. I didn't know that. I updated it now.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution would be to search for transportation to [Indiana University](http://www.iu.edu) so for example:

- [Go Express Chicago](http://goexpresschicago.com/full-schedule)
- [Catch a Ride](http://www.catcharide.com/)
- [Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Chicago-O-Hare-Airport-ORD/Bloomington-IN-Indiana-University-Wilkie)
- [Rural Transit](http://services.bloomington.ivytech.edu/)
- [Hoosier Ride](http://hoosierride.com/)

Given the number of options now it is also worth mentioning that you could simply drive to Chicago meet your friend and drive back.

Comment: Picking someone up in Chicago from Bloomington is a long day. It's about four hours driving, each way.

Comment: @phoog Been there and done that and while being the long day it's not out of the realm of impossible.

Comment: True, but people often underestimate distances in the US. A European would be unlikely to consider driving the similar distance between Amsterdam and Frankfurt to pick someone up at the airport, nor would someone from the east coast be likely to drive the even shorter distance between NYC and Boston for the same reason (in fairness, the drive time is generally longer because of traffic). On the other hand, when I lived in Bloomington it wasn't entirely unusual to visit Chicago for an evening out. Still, it seems irresponsible to mention the possibility of driving without noting the distance.

Comment: That's what Google maps are for! :)